# Can the primary operating system be hacked when using another one on an external drive?

Tags: privacy, operating-systems

I have Kali Linux on an external flash drive that is 128GB. I would like to build a PC with my friend but I don't know which operating system to put on it. I want to be able to play games and I know that the parts I've searched for are pretty fast and I also know that Windows is the best for it. But I am also aware that Windows is the most vulnerable OS compared to Linux and MacOS. I know that MacOS is secure because things like SIP (System Integrity Protection) and other features that I'm unaware of exist. My question is, is it possible to get your other operating system hacked even while Kali Linux is plugged in and the primary OS is "Sleeping"? If so, then I'd rather have security over games with MacOS. But if not, then I'm going to stick with Windows for the entertainment.

Comment: _"Windows is the most vulnerable OS compared to Linux and MacOS"_. That's really a tough statement to make... Just use the OS that has the features you need, and enable full disk encryption or run Kali in a VM to protect the host from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is it possible to get your other operating system hacked even while Kali Linux is plugged in and the primary OS is "Sleeping"?

If you don't have full-disk encryption enabled on your computer, and you get hacked while running another OS from an external drive, then the attacker can mount the main computer's drive and compromise your main OS by modify some of its components to introduce a backdoor. However, this is not OS dependent and can happen even if your main OS is MacOS or Linux. The solution is what multithr3at3d says, either enable full disk encryption so the attacker cannot modify the OS as they like (note however that they may be able to corrupt it), or else run Kali in a virtual machine, which will completely isolate Kali from the host.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Full-disk encryption seems like a good idea. My plan is to use windows and kali on 2 separate hard drives and macOS as an internal one. So do you know how to enable full disk encryption? Is that the same as FileVault?

Comment: @MatthewSchell Not familiar with macs but from a quick google search, yes it does seem like filevault offers  disk encryption

Comment: How about for Windows?

Comment: @MatthewSchell You could use Microsoft's [Bitlocker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-device-encryption-overview-windows-10) or [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/code/VeraCrypt/)

Comment: @Matthew Schell -   A couple of notes. **(1)** The primary OS is not sleeping! There may be another bootable partition that is currently not mounted or running, but *sleeping* has a different meaning. **(2)** A bootable drive has a non-encrypted boot partition even using Full-Disk Encryption. This is modifiable by external boot systems (Kali). To be useful, it would have to be a variant of what's referred to as an *Evil Maid Attack*.

Comment: @user10216038. I didn't mean to say sleeping. I was writing this post late at night and I just didn't know what to really put there haha. What does sleeping really mean? And is there a way to encrypt the boot partition like you said could be vulnerable to the Evil Maid Attack?

Comment: @Matthew Schell - You can't encrypt everything because you need a starting point, a.k.a. a *boot*. I wouldn't wouldn't worry about *Evil Maid*, it's a pretty hard core attack you are unlikely to ever encounter.